# Ubuntu 12.04 with Mate and video card issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, docky, mate

My laptop has a nVidia Geforce G105M that is why I installed the appropriate nVidia drivers to make it work properly. As I am a truly Gnome 2 lover I switched from Unity to Mate. But apparently in Mate, although the drivers seem to be correctly activated, Docky can't render 3D because it's like the video card features are in some way disabled. So how do I make myself sure that the drivers are actually working?

Comment: I'm not a MATE user ... so I'm assuming its something like 10.04 Ubuntu - do you have visual effects correctly set in the Appearance window?  Is compiz running?

Answer (score 0):

As you may know MATE is a fork of Gnome 2, also as you may know Gnome 2 is not supported anymore, now. If you open the Terminal and type: `lsmod` and you see `nvidia` then the drivers are running, the problem now would be that the MATE composting manager is not running.

Metacity which is/was Gnome compositing Manager had/has basic 3D support, I'm guessing the same is for the the forked MATE compositing manager, so you could try to:

- Run the composite manager in a Terminal
- Run another composite manager such as xcompmgr (a basic composite
  manager that handles 3D) or Compiz.